# django related field got invalid lookup

Tags: django

I have nasty list comprehension that I'd like to simplify with a basic django query but I'm running into a `Related Field got invalid lookup: document_task_type`

```
result = [x for x in self.quote_tasks if x.task_definition.document_task_type == 'GENCNTR'][0]
```

query resulting in error

```
self.quote_tasks.filter(task_definition__document_task_type = 'GENCNTR')
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting your model would help, but I guess it's field lookup (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups).

Try changing the code to

```
ret = self.quote_tasks.filter(task_definition__document_task_type__exact='GENCNTR')
```

Don't forget to add a try-catch block if you want to use `[0]` at the end (since the QuerySet could be empty).